# Figuring out where image data is being stored

Tags: php, image-processing

Well in a particular website when I upload the image and then try to get the link of the image I get this:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,thebase64encodeOfMyImageCode
```

I have seen this in  many of the website. After decoding the `base64` code I find that its the code of my image file (guessed out by uploading `svg` image file ) . Can any one tell me how this work and where the image is actually being stored . There is no direct URL like `website.com/image.svg` etc. This is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When base64 encoding is used for the image - you simply cannot know where the actual image is stored, if it is available at all. It might not be stored on a file at all, but only on a database, or might be stored outside the domain. On some occasions, such images are generated in real time and not stored on a disk at all.

Comment: So there is no way to figure out where the data is actually being stored ? I mean the exact url of the image file ?

Comment: Correct. Not based on this data.

Answer (score 2):

This image is not stored in a file. All the data for the image is stored in the data URL. The server most likely is storing this data in a database, which is then outputted in the webpage inline.

For more information, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)